# communication between run() method and other class method (java threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, list, methods

i have task to do and i'm little stuck. I have to make 4 services (A,B,C,D). Every service should have his own thread. They should start in sequence and run. If service A starts then can start service B, if service B starts if service C starts then can start service D. I manage to create service and their threads but i dont know how should i create communication between start() and priority() method in PriorityService class. I wan to check if service(thread) A is alive and if it is I want to move to second service from list and so on.  Is that possible? Do you have any other ideas how to write service dependency?
Any advice is useful. Tnx.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class CreateThread extends Thread{
    private String thread_name;
    public int numb;
    public CreateThread(String thread_name, int i){
        this.thread_name=thread_name;
        System.out.println("Thread " + thread_name + " has started.");
        i=numb;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println(thread_name + " status = " + t.getState());
            System.out.println(thread_name + " status = " + t.isAlive());
            t.join();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}

class PriorityService extends ArrayList<Service> {
    public void priority()
    {
         int i=0;
         while(i<size()){
                System.out.println("evo me"+ get(i).service_name);
                    if(get(i).service_name=="Service A")
                        get(i).StartService(get(i).service_name, get(i).thread_name, i);
                    i++;
            }
    }
 }

public class Service {
    public String service_name;
    public String thread_name;

    public Service(String service_name, String thread_name){
        this.service_name=service_name;
        this.thread_name=thread_name;
    }

    public void StartService(String service_name, String thread_name, int i) {
        System.out.println("Service " + service_name + " has started.");
        Thread t=new Thread(new CreateThread(thread_name, i));
        t.start();
    }

    public void StopService() {}
    public static void main (String[] args){
        PriorityService p_s=new PriorityService();
        Service service_A = new Service("Service A", "Thread A");
        Service service_B = new Service("Service B", "Thread B");
        Service service_C = new Service("Service C", "Thread C");
        Service service_D = new Service("Service D", "Thread D");
        p_s.add(service_A);
        p_s.add(service_B);
        p_s.add(service_C);
        p_s.add(service_D);
        p_s.priority();

        for(Service s: p_s)
            System.out.println(s.service_name);     

    }
}
```

Comment: Reading through - `i=numb` in the constructor of `CreateThread` seems wrong, shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Calling `join` on the current thread won't do anything.

Comment: that peace of code stayed there because I was trying to send int i from while loop to CreateThread class and then if that thread is alive do i++ witch becomes numb in run() method and send that to while loop in priority() method. I dont know if that is good idea because i'm new in programming.

Comment: @seling with join method i'm trying to run all threads without stooping. As i said i dont know if anything from this is good idea :S I'm confused...

Comment: Calling `Thread.currentThread().join();` will hang until the thread is interrupted which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Would it be correct to summarize your problem as "How to create threads such that they start in a certain order" - note that *start* is a problematic word as a thread could start and do no work or start and do all of its work.

Comment: @selig yes i'm trying to do that-> How to create threads such that they start in a certain order. I'm I on the good way? Tnx for help

Comment: It's quite clumsy. Is the order in which the threads should start a total order i.e. is it A then B then C or is it partial i.e. A before B and A before C (but no order between B and C)? If it's a total order then I would just number threads and use a counter. If it's partial I would create a data structure which represented this order.

Comment: @selig it is actually A before B and A before C. Then B and C can start without order and then D can start only if B has started i.e D deepens on B, B deepens on A and C deepens on A. So in this case i should create data structure? Do you have any examples? Because i dont know how to do it? What should i use?

Comment: This solution didn't help you out http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085730/1981279 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating different threads for each services, then you cannot control the execution is the threads (e.g. by setting its priority, etc). Priority is just an indicator for OS, but can not be guarantee that threads with higher priority runs first.

Only way you can do this by inter-thread communication using wait, notify, join, etc.

But I think in case you case the solution could be, create separate thread for one combination of Service A, B, C & D.

Comment: did i understand you good, you think that i should create Threads for Service separate and then  pass them to the Service and then just in priority() method i should control calling of run() method for every service?

Comment: What I am saying is to re-design in such a way that your services (A, B, C, D) executes serially in one thread. Create many threads for such executions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Latches for this.

You can use 2 Latches for one for each pair of threads and that should do your job. So one Latch will be there for Threads A and B, which implies till bothof them are up and running they can't proceed. Similarly for C and D.

This [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/countdownlatch-example-in-java.html) has an example showing use of Latch, just take a look.